# SVG alternative to display complex vector files in Processing.org with OPENGL or P3D libraries

Tags: opengl, 3d, svg, processing, vector-graphics

I am trying to display SVG files in 3D with Processing.org using either the OPENGL or P3D libraries. The issue, [documented here](http://processing.org/reference/shape_.html) (and other places: [1](http://processing.org/bugs/bugzilla/947.html), [2](http://code.google.com/p/processing/issues/detail?id=291), and [an undesirable library hack](http://processing.org/discourse/beta/num_1189397082.html)), is that these renderers to not support complex shapes (those with holes or complicated breaks).

Is there an alternative to SVG for the graphics, or another library I could use?

Below are image files and code samples. This first image uses the default renderer:

[image: with default renderer]

This image uses OPENGL 3D library. You can see it struggles to reproduce the SVG files.

[image: with OPENGL 3d renderer]

[I've posted a zip of this sketch with images](http://owenmundy.com/work/_sketches/opengl_svg_issue.zip) and code below. Uncomment the OPENGL line and comment the default line to see the problem.

```
import processing.opengl.*; 

float wh = 0;

void setup() {
  //size(600, 600, OPENGL); // use OPENGL
  size(600, 600); // use default library
  background(255);
  smooth();
}

void draw() {
  wh = random(40, 200);  
  PShape s;
  String file = "gear" + ceil(random(0, 12)) + ".svg";
  s = loadShape(file);
  shape(s, random(-20, width), random(-20, height), wh, wh);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Geomerative library which works fine with the OPENGL renderer.
You can find it right there:
http://www.ricardmarxer.com/geomerative/

This is your provided example adapted to work with Geomerative that works fine with OPENGL:

```
import geomerative.*;
import processing.opengl.*; 

float wh = 0;

void setup() {
    size(600, 600, OPENGL);
    RG.init( this );

    background(255);
    smooth();
}

void draw() {
    wh = random(40, 200);  
    RShape s;
    String file = "gear" + ceil(random(0, 12)) + ".svg";
    s = RG.loadShape(file);

    pushMatrix();
    translate(random(-20, width), random(-20, height));
    s.draw();
    popMatrix();
}
```

Comment: I noticed this is fixed also in Processing 3.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.hypeframework.org The Hype Framework, there is some cool tutorials on skillshare.com